# ACTION_SEND intent not sharing text

Tags: android-intent, android-sharing, data-sharing

I have created a share intent for intent chooser.

```
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.type = "video/*"
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, db.getShareMessageDao().getVideoShareMessage() + "\n\n" + shortLink)
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing")
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_video)))
```

In this intent I have added a video to share which is being shared successfully but the `EXTRA_TEXT` is not sharing with the intent.
Any idea why is it not working?

Comment: Why don't you add the `android` tag? You get more views on the question that way.

Comment: I have already added tags. Can you suggest me more tags which I can add to increase the reach of my question. @SambhavKhandelwal

Comment: To increase views, you have to add some commonly searched tags like [tag:android], [tag:java] and etc... Instead of adding only the sub tags like how you have you should use their parent tags which are more commonly searched